# Contando quantidade de resultados de um Split()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, split

Tenho uma string que está assim:

> Sim,Não,Talvez

E eu tenho um código que preciso colocar esses resultados da string separadamente em uma `<option>` de um `<select>`.

Pretendo fazer isso atraves de um `for()`. mas eu preciso contar os resultados do meu split para colocar lá, por exemplo, pegando essa string, ficaria:

> Sim Não Talvez

os resultados de um `string.Split(",");`. Mas eu preciso do número de quantos resultados deram, que nesse caso seriam 3.

```
1: Sim
2: Não
3: Talvez
```

Como eu faço para contar quantos resultados eu obtive em um split?

Estou fazendo em .NET e tentei colocar um `.Count` pra ver se colava, mas não deu... como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você faz um [Split](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8) de um texto com esse formato (`Sim,Não,Talvez`) vai retornar um `array` simples e imutável com a quantidade de informações geradas por essa condição e para saber a quantidade utilize `Length`, ***exemplo***:

```
string texto = "Sim,Não,Talvez";
string[] textos = texto.Split(',');
textos.Length; // 3 itens
```

---

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Como: Analisar cadeias de caracteres usando String.Split (Guia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split)
- [String.Split Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hmm... funcionou. Só mais uma pergunta. Sabe como eu faço para alterar sua ordem? Por exemplo, neste caso ficaria `Sim Não Talvez`, mas teria alguma forma de eu deixar a ordem assim assim `Talvez Não Sim`?

Comment: Já é uma outra pergunta, mexer na ordem precisa saber qual é a condição por você estipulada para isso acontecer, você quer o `array` ao inverso ??? qual é a regra

Comment: sim.. o array ao inverso só

Comment: faz o for do maior para o menor, exemplo `for(int i = textos.Length - 1; i >= 0;i--){}`

Comment: ou utilize `Array.Reverse(textos)`  e imprima normalmente ... eu não vou colocar na resposta porque não faz parte da pergunta ...

Comment: Obrigado, vai me ajudar.